# importar abecedario español python

Tags: python, python-2.x

Necesito trabajar con el abecedario español pero no encuentro que paquete importar.

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
```

Voy a trabajar con el en mayúsculas pero eso no me es de gran importancia, el problema es que este paquete **no** contiene la ñ ¿Hay alguno que sí? No consigo encontrarlo si lo hay.

En caso de no haberlo, se pueden modificar los paquetes? Y añadir yo la ñ

¡Salud y gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No veo la necesidad de modificar el paquete. Una vez has importado `ascii_uppercase`, lo que tienes bajo ese nombre es en realidad una variable de tipo `str` que contiene `"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"`. Fácilmente puedes añadir la eñe así:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
ascii_uppercase += 'Ñ'
```

o ya puestos cambiarla de nombre:

```
spanish_uppercase = ascii_uppercase + 'Ñ'
```

Plantéate si no tendrás que añadir también vocales acentuadas y Ü.

#### Actualización

Si estás trabajando con Python2, entonces necesitarás especificar que la Ñ es un carácter unicode, para que guarde su código Unicode, en lugar de la codificación utf8 o la que use tu editor (en python3 no es necesario pues por defecto las cadenas son unicode). Así:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
spanish_uppercase = ascii_uppercase + u'Ñ'
```

Comment: Gracias, lo de las mayúsculas es que todo mi texto siempre está en mayúsculas, cómo ya dije no tiene gran importancia

Comment: El problema de esta solución es que en vez de aparecer una 'Ñ' me aparece '\xc3\x91' y esto luego me genera problemas...

Comment: añadido, si me obligan a emplear la versión 2

Comment: @NEA actualizada respuesta

Comment: En los diccionarios no se puede unicode? Es que hago `abecedario_esp[cnt+1] = u'Ñ'` y me da un error de unicodeWarning. Disculpa tanta pregunta

Comment: En principio si se puede ¿De qué tipo es `abecedario_esp`? ¿Es un diccionario? ¿Qué error concreto te da esa línea? ¿Estás seguro de que es esa línea la que da el error?

Comment: Disculpa no da error pero en vez de salir la Ñ, ahora sale u'\xd1'

Comment: Esa es la representación interna python. El código Unicode de la `Ñ`  es el `D1`, y cuando intentas ver la representación de una cadena unicode que contenga caracteres no ascii, python los muestra de esa forma. Eso sólo afecta al volcado en un intérprete interactivo, pero no a lo que sale cuando haces `print`. Es decir, una variable `a = u'Ñ'`, se volcará como `u'\xd1'` cuando la veas en su forma "representación" (por ejemplo si forma parte de una lista o de un diccionario que estás volcando), pero se verá correctamente como `Ñ` cuando hagas `print a`.

Comment: Vale muchas gracias, ya lo entiendo. Es que al seguir saliendo u'\xd1' pensaba que no lo hacía bien. El problema lo tengo en otro lado, pero mejor publicaré una preguna nueva.